# Data Loader - Unable to Proceed beyond Edit Your Query

Tags: query, data-loader, data, data-export

I'm trying to export data using Data Loader but I keep running into the same issue. This seems to be happening regardless of which object I'm trying to export data for - no matter what I select, I'm not able click Next or Finish to proceed beyond Step 3: Edit your Query.

[image]

Has anybody encountered this issue before? I have downloaded the latest version of Data Loader but I'm still unable to move forward as the buttons are greyed out. Please can somebody offer me some guidance with this?

Comment: I have Dataloader open all the time and sometimes I need to log out and log back in in order to use the tool. It might be worthwhile to just log out and back in again and see if you are able to press "Finish"?